# How can I select from the same table with different where conditions and differnet group by conditions in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically this is what I am trying to achieve but I don't know how to do it in a single query, I don't know if it can be done in a single query.

**[SQL fiddle with example data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cd2cbb/1)**

Query 1 :

```
SELECT 
    cityId, 
    COUNT(cityId) 
FROM 
    data 
WHERE 
    streetId IS NULL 
    AND houseId IS NULL 
GROUP BY cityId
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT 
    cityId, 
    streetId, 
    COUNT(streetId) 
FROM 
    data 
WHERE 
    streetId IS NOT NULL 
    AND houseId IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
    streetId
```

Query 3 :

```
SELECT 
    cityId, 
    streetId, 
    houseId, 
    COUNT(houseId) 
FROM
    data 
WHERE 
    streetId IS NOT NULL 
    AND houseId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    houseId
```

Is there a way to do this in a single query ?

Comment: Because of the different grouping requirements it's probably not possible to get these results more efficiently in a single query. But what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the DB Fiddle ! Now you should just need to show us your expected output...

Comment: @Nick In the real case I need to use this for notifications and I need to constantly query the database to check for new ones, I thought it would be more efficient to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just use `UNION ALL` to put together the results of the 3 queries. This requires you to adapt the queries so they all return the same columns. I filled the additional columns with `NULL` when not available in the original query.

```
SELECT 
    cityId, 
    NULL street_id, 
    NULL houseId, 
    COUNT(cityId) cnt 
FROM
    data 
WHERE 
    streetId IS NULL 
    AND houseId IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
    cityId
UNION ALL SELECT 
    cityId, 
    streetId, 
    NULL, 
    COUNT(streetId) 
FROM 
    data 
WHERE 
    streetId IS NOT NULL 
    AND houseId IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
    streetId
UNION ALL SELECT 
    cityId, 
    streetId, 
    houseId, 
    COUNT(houseId) 
FROM
    data 
WHERE 
    streetId IS NOT NULL 
    AND houseId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    houseId
```

**[Results in your db fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cd2cbb/3)** :

```
cityId  street_id   houseId     cnt
-----------------------------------
1       (null)      (null)      2
2       (null)      (null)      1
2       2           (null)      1
3       3           (null)      5
6       4           3           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this produce what you want?

```
SELECT cityId, streetId, houseId, COUNT(*) 
FROM data 
GROUP BY cityId, streetId, houseId;
```